# Creating a Django form from a dictionary of objects

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I feel like this must be really simple, but after a couple of days of trying I'm officially clueless.

I have a dictionary where the keys are objects and the values are lists of objects. Here's how I want to use that info to construct a form:

```
for object in dictionary:
    name_of_field = object.slug
    name_of_field = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widgets=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=dictionary[object])
```

Of course, just putting name_of_field in there twice doesn't work to generate dynamically named fields. What this actually does is create a single field called "name_of_field" using the final object it iterates over. I wish it would create a field for every key in the dictionary, named using the key object's slug and with a choice set of that key's values.

Is there a way to loop through this dictionary and create the form fields I want? I feel like the answer lies in superclassing `__init__`, but I still can't wrap my head around how to get multiple fields with different names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say where you are using this code. You should be putting it into the form's `__init__` method, from where you can reference `self.fields`:

```
class DynamicForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dynamic_fields = kwargs.pop('dynamic_fields')
        super(DynamicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for key, value in dynamic_fields:
            self.fields[key.slug] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=value)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help - this is the second question of mine you've answered this week! Please forgive my ignorance, but I'm still having a little trouble. I get a KeyError on line three of the code you provided. I don't really understand how the kwargs.pop('dynamic_fields') works - do I generate my dictionary and call upon it when I instantiate the form in views.py? Or should that dictionary be generated in forms.py? Right now I have the dictionary generated below the `__init__` method in the form class. I also tried it as a global and in views.py, but received KeyErrors. THANK YOU AGAIN!!!

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have said - you should define the dict in your view and pass it in when you instantiate the form: `form = DynamicForm(request.POST, dynamic_fields=my_dict)`.

Comment: That did the trick. Can't thank you enough! I sincerely appreciate the time you spent on this.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I want to contribute to this question although it is really old, because I could not solve my question with the answer alone.

For a given model with the form:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    data = models.JSONField()
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

a dynamically created form can be created (careful, this is a simplified case, where all products of the same store share the same keys in the `JSONField`):

```
class ProductForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, first_product, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["number"] = forms.IntegerField(required = True)
        for key in first_product.data.keys():
            self.fields[key] = forms.CharField(required = False)
            
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["number", "data"]
```

The form must be called by handing it the `first_product` variable in the view:

```
class SomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "appName/sometemplatename.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        store = Store.objects.get(user = self.request.user)
        tmp = Product.objects.filter(store = store).first()
        context["testform"] = ProductForm(first_product = tmp)
        return context
```

This is a vastly general approach to start from.