# Django - Creating form fields by iterating through data in my database?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I would like to set up a form based on the values I have stored in my database.

Let's say I have some models like this:

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=350)

class Answers(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Questions)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=350)
```

And I would like to create a form in this way:

```
for x in Questions:
   answer = forms.CharField(label = x.question)
```

And thereby having exactly the number of answer fields in the form as there are questions stored in the database. Any ideas?

Comment: I had a similar question recently. See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275562/creating-a-django-form-from-a-dictionary-of-objects. In your dictionary, the keys would be question objects and the values would be query sets of the associated answer objects.

Comment: @souldeux, surprisingly enough, it did help! It pointed me towards ModelChoiceField/ChoiceField which is basically the key to solving this problem. It also showed me that the iteration of fields goes in init and not just loose within the form class. I will post my solution below in case anyone can help me find a cleaner solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with. Seems to work okay, but I feel like there is a cleaner solution I am missing.

in my forms.py:

```
class AnswerForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(AnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

         for x in Questions.objects.all():
         self.fields[x.question] = ModelChoiceField(queryset=.....
```