# Django - Dictionary of Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, dictionary

I'm trying to implement a dictionary of forms where two fills are initialized with some values I have. I'm passing this through a Jquery function but when its going to add it to the template, the jquery function has an error that says `Cannot set property 'value' of null` when trying to execute this `document.getElementById('example1').value = example;`

My code here:

view.py

```
    def exampleCaesar(request):

if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "GET":
    form = caesarCipher(request.GET or None)

    if form.is_valid:
        wordToEncrypt = request.GET.get('word')
        wordToEncrypt = wordToEncrypt.upper()
        wordLength = len(request.GET.get('word'))
        key = request.GET.get('the_key')

        print(wordLength)
        print(key)
        equations = {}

        for x in range(wordLength):
            exampleForm = caesarCipher(initial={'letterOfWord' : wordToEncrypt[x], 'key' : key})
            ##print(exampleForm)
            if exampleForm.is_valid:
                equations = (exampleForm)
                print(equations)
        context = { 'equations' : equations

        }

        return render(request, "content/exampleCaesar.html", context)
```

Javascript file

```
    $("#encryptButton").on({
    click : function() {
      var variable = document.getElementById('id_plaintext');
      console.log(variable.value)
      $.ajax( {
        url: "/exampleCaesar",
        type : "GET",
        data: { CSRF: 'csrf_token',
                word: $('#id_plaintext').val(),
                the_key: $('#id_key').val()
        },

        success : function(example) {
          $('#example1').show();
          $('#example1').html(example);
          document.getElementById('example1').value = example;

          console.log(example);

        }

      }); //END OF Ajax
    } //END OF FUNCTION
}); //END OF encryptButton
```

Template file

```
  {% for letterOfWord, key in equations.items %}
  <form onsubmit="return false;" method="GET" class="exaSubmit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="example1" type="hidden">
        ( {{ letterOfWord }} + {{ keyToUse }} ) MOD 26 =
          {{ letterToFill }} <button name="action" class="validateButton" value="validate"> Validate </button>  <br>
          </div>
        </form>

  {% endfor %}
```

I believe I'm not filling the dictionary the right way. When I try to print it out in the console to see the values, only the names of the fields are but not the values. My bets are in this section but not entirely sure how's that possible when I'm appending the information to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275562/creating-a-django-form-from-a-dictionary-of-objects?rq=1

Comment: and to get values instead of field name, you have to add

def __unicode__(self):
      return unicode(self.field_name)

in model.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what u are suggesting? Can't seem to understand the post you referenced.

Comment: Please show the full view, and the full context of the JS. What is calling that `ajax()` function? And don't swear; there's no call for it here.

Comment: Added the information you requested. And sorry, that comment in the code was done by one of my friends that was working on this last night.

Comment: Thanks. Why are you setting the contents of `example1` both with jQuery *and* pure JS? Why do you need that `getElementById` call at all?

Comment: If I delete the getElementById, then no error but my template doesn't generate the forms passed by in the dictionary.

Comment: I can't understand what you're saying. The line `$('#example1').html(example);` already sets the contents of the response into the example div. The following line attempts to do the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101303/discussion-between-silvestrini-and-daniel-roseman).

Comment: Please get in the chat so I can explain you what I'm trying to implement.